# Exist an easy way to find a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}_3$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(K_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2)$?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, automorphism-group

$\operatorname{Aut}(K_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2)$ is isomorphic to  group of order 168.

I don't know how to start to find an element of $\operatorname{Aut}(K_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2)$ such that his order divides $3$ (non-trivial).

I appreciate your help.

Comment: what's $K_4$? Whatever it is, $168$ is not such a big number, and one could resort to exhaustive search.

Comment: Presumably the Klein four group, in which case $Aut(K_{4} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \cong Aut(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) \cong GL_{3}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, in which case one can compute explicitly with matrices.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, $K_{4}$ is the Klein 4 Group. Maybe exist a more easy way.

Answer (score 0):

If $K_4$ is the Klein $4$-group, then $K_4\times Z_2\cong Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_2$. This group has an order $3$ automorphism cycling the three factors, i.e., $(a,b,c)\mapsto(b,c,a)$.